# How to position the nav bar without being moved by the other elements?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a navbar and adding elements next to it, but I don't know why the other element is positioning in a higher place, making the navbar to move down.

[This is what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stOVc.png)

What do I need to do so the navbar stays [where it's supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1HPh.png)

and have the ability to move freely the other objects, so I can place them in the middle of the website without problem

Here is the code:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    background: #224fb1;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
}

#iconmenu{
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.title{
    display: flex;
    justify-self: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
}


.titphp{
    font-size: large;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    height: 860px;
    width: 170px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

}

#opcnav{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;


    

}
#opcnav:hover{
    background-color: #91B6E4;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    
}
#botnav{    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    display: block;

    
}
#botnav:hover{
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #91B6E4;
    color: white;
}

#datosalumno{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;



    
}
#fotoalumno{
    margin: 10px;
    /* border-radius: 10px; */
}

#calendar{
    margin: 5px;
}


/* Parte del calendario */
#calendario{
    border: 4px double black;
    max-width: 536px;
    background-color: #fffafa;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
#diasc{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px;
}
#diasc th, #diasc td {
    font: normal 14pt arial; 
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
}
#diasc th{
    color: #990099;
    background-color: #5ecdec;
}
#diasc td{
    color: #492736;
    background-color: #9bf5ff;
}
#fechaactual {
    font: bold 12pt arial;
    padding: 0.4em;
}
#fechaactual i {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#fechaactual i:hover{
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#buscafecha{
    background-color: #663366;
    color: #9bf5ff;
    padding: 5px;
}
#buscafecha select, #buscafecha input {
    background-color: #9bf5ff;
    color: #990099;
    font: bold 10pt arial;
}
#buscafecha [type=text]{
    text-align: center;
}
#buscafecha [type=button]{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prac/calestilo.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendario.js"></script>
    <title>Calendario 2.0</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cab">
        <header>
            <div>
      <img src="prac/icons/hambu.png" alt="Menu" id="iconmenu"
                        height="40px"
                        
                    >
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="title">Calendario</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
  <div id="navbar">
            <img src="prac/icons/logo_uni_2016.png" alt="Logo Uni"
            height="50px">
            <ul id="listnav" class="nav-menu">
            <li id="opcnav"><a id="botnav" href="http://localhost/calendario/Prac/miinfo.html" title="Mi Perfil" target="blank"><img src="prac/icons/user.png" alt="Mi Información"
                height="15px"> Mi Perifl</a>
            <li id="opcnav"> <img src="prac/icons/asistencia.png" alt="Asistencia"
                height="15px"> Asistencia
            <li id="opcnav"><a id="botnav" href="http://localhost/calendario/Calendario.php" title="Calendario" target="blank" > <img src="prac/icons/calendar.png" alt="Calendario"
                height="15px"> Calendario</a>
            <li id="opcnav">En Proceso...
            </ul>
            
        </div>

        <!-- Esta es la parte del calendario -->

        <div id="calendario">
            <div id="anterior" onclick="mesantes()"></div>
            <div id="posterior" onclick="mesdespues()"></div>
            <h2 id="titulos"></h2>
            <table id="diasc">
            <tr id="fila0"><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
            <tr id="fila1"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr id="fila2"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr id="fila3"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr id="fila4"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr id="fila5"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr id="fila6"><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <div id="fechaactual"><i onclick="actualizar()">HOY: </i></div>
                    <div id="buscafecha">
                        <form action="#" name="buscar">
                        <p>Buscar ... MES
                            <select name="buscames">
                            <option value="0">Enero</option>
                            <option value="1">Febrero</option>
                            <option value="2">Marzo</option>
                            <option value="3">Abril</option>
                            <option value="4">Mayo</option>
                            <option value="5">Junio</option>
                            <option value="6">Julio</option>
                            <option value="7">Agosto</option>
                            <option value="8">Septiembre</option>
                            <option value="9">Octubre</option>
                            <option value="10">Noviembre</option>
                            <option value="11">Diciembre</option>
                            </select>
                        ... AÑO ...
                            <input type="text" name="buscaanno" maxlength="4" size="4" />
                        ... 
                            <input type="button" value="BUSCAR" onclick="mifecha()" />
                        </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
     </div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion

In today era, we have some powerful things like flex and grid to build a website layout. So plz try to use `display: flex;` or `display: grid;` insted of `display: inline-block;`.

### How to do

Just wrap the `<nav id="navbar">` and `<div id="calendario">` to the `<div>` and give it a style `display: flex`. And then there's no need for `display: inline-block;` just remove it from both childs. One more fix to adjust the height of `<div id="calendario">` by `height: fit-content;`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background: #224fb1;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-self: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
}

#iconmenu {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-self: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}


.titphp {
    font-size: large;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    height: 860px;
    width: 170px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
    /* display: inline-block; */
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

}

#opcnav {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;




}

#opcnav:hover {
    background-color: #91B6E4;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;

}

#botnav {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    display: block;


}

#botnav:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #91B6E4;
    color: white;
}

#datosalumno {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.12);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;




}

#fotoalumno {
    margin: 10px;
    /* border-radius: 10px; */
}

#calendar {
    margin: 5px;
}


/* Parte del calendario */
#calendario {
    border: 4px double black;
    max-width: 536px;
    background-color: #fffafa;
    text-align: center;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}

#diasc {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px;
}

#diasc th,
#diasc td {
    font: normal 14pt arial;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
}

#diasc th {
    color: #990099;
    background-color: #5ecdec;
}

#diasc td {
    color: #492736;
    background-color: #9bf5ff;
}

#fechaactual {
    font: bold 12pt arial;
    padding: 0.4em;
}

#fechaactual i {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#fechaactual i:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#buscafecha {
    background-color: #663366;
    color: #9bf5ff;
    padding: 5px;
}

#buscafecha select,
#buscafecha input {
    background-color: #9bf5ff;
    color: #990099;
    font: bold 10pt arial;
}

#buscafecha [type=text] {
    text-align: center;
}

#buscafecha [type=button] {
    cursor: pointer;
}



#main{
    display: flex;
}


#calendario {
    height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prac/calestilo.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="calendario.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Calendario 2.0</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="cab">
        <header>
            <div>
                <img src="prac/icons/hambu.png" alt="Menu" id="iconmenu" height="40px">
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="title">Calendario</h1>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="navbar">
            <img src="prac/icons/logo_uni_2016.png" alt="Logo Uni" height="50px">
            <ul id="listnav" class="nav-menu">
                <li id="opcnav"><a id="botnav" href="http://localhost/calendario/Prac/miinfo.html" title="Mi Perfil"
                        target="blank"><img src="prac/icons/user.png" alt="Mi Información" height="15px"> Mi Perifl</a>
                <li id="opcnav"> <img src="prac/icons/asistencia.png" alt="Asistencia" height="15px"> Asistencia
                <li id="opcnav"><a id="botnav" href="http://localhost/calendario/Calendario.php" title="Calendario"
                        target="blank"> <img src="prac/icons/calendar.png" alt="Calendario" height="15px">
                        Calendario</a>
                <li id="opcnav">En Proceso...
            </ul>

        </div>

        <!-- Esta es la parte del calendario -->

        <div id="calendario">
            <div id="anterior" onclick="mesantes()"></div>
            <div id="posterior" onclick="mesdespues()"></div>
            <h2 id="titulos"></h2>
            <table id="diasc">
                <tr id="fila0">
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="fila1">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="fila2">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="fila3">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="fila4">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="fila5">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="fila6">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="fechaactual"><i onclick="actualizar()">HOY: </i></div>
            <div id="buscafecha">
                <form action="#" name="buscar">
                    <p>Buscar ... MES
                        <select name="buscames">
                            <option value="0">Enero</option>
                            <option value="1">Febrero</option>
                            <option value="2">Marzo</option>
                            <option value="3">Abril</option>
                            <option value="4">Mayo</option>
                            <option value="5">Junio</option>
                            <option value="6">Julio</option>
                            <option value="7">Agosto</option>
                            <option value="8">Septiembre</option>
                            <option value="9">Octubre</option>
                            <option value="10">Noviembre</option>
                            <option value="11">Diciembre</option>
                        </select>
                        ... AÑO ...
                        <input type="text" name="buscaanno" maxlength="4" size="4" />
                        ...
                        <input type="button" value="BUSCAR" onclick="mifecha()" />
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```